# Table or Collection view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm creating a single column photo app with dynamic heights. Right now I'm using a tableview but I'm far from done. While I'm in the early stage of development & still new to objective -c, I'm wondering which would be the best solution for this app. I don't know why, but something tells me that a table view isn't the way to go.

Should I use a Table or Collection view & why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty much okay to use either. One thing to keep in mind is it is a bit easier to manage edit mode on a UITableView, so if you need that it might be best to stick with it.

On the other hand, if you'd like to extend the same UIViewController to work on the iPad and display images in a grid, UICollectionView is probably your answer.

Comment: UICollection it is.. Thx :)

Comment: No problem! As Bishal mentioned UICollectionView is only available in iOS 6 and above.. but I don't see the point in supporting anything lower anymore anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Table View is very powerful and you can do almost anything with it. 
And when it comes to Collection View it is the advanced form ( in terms of easy to design ) of TableView where you have lots of layouts options.

But the sad part is Collection View require iOS 6+ so if you need to support iOS 5 in your app. Table view is the only way to go. Or you have lots of third party framework like collection view which works in iOS5.